# Symfony Multiple Checkboxes Saving to mySQL

Tags: mysql, forms, symfony-1.4

I have a form and one of the fields is a multiple choice, meaning people can select more than 1 checkbox for that 1 answer.  All of the answers are numbers (i.e. 01, 02, 03, etc) so I set it to INTEGER in the `schema.yml` but when users try to submit the form, it saves it with a value of 0.   If they only select 1 checkbox, it saves fine, but more than 1 and it doesn't save anything.

What "type" should I set this one.

**schema.yml**

```
    Ticket:
      connection: doctrine
      tableName: ticket
      columns:
        ticketid:
          type: integer(10)
          fixed: false
          unsigned: false
          primary: true
          autoincrement: true
        num01:
          type:  integer()
          notnull: true
          autoincrement: false
```

Comment: Can we have the whole schema for the answer model?

Comment: Here is the entire schema for the Ticket model.

Comment: You want to save more than one information inside one field? If a user select 2 answers, what do you expected to be inside `num01`?

Comment: Yes, the field "num01" is a multiple choice and there can be up to 5 answers.  I'm thinking "integer" is not the right type.

Comment: It's totally not the right type. You shoud use an external table for that. In a way that Ticket -> hasMany -> Answers. It will be very much easier to handle.

Comment: What about using "array" as a type?  Any objections?  I tried it just to test and it looks like it saves all the values.  I'm still trying to figure out how ti display them on the `showSuccess` page, but it looks like it saves it in the single field.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What if you want to know how many Ticket has answers 02 and 03 ? Or if a Ticket has 01 and not 02 ? It'll be harder if you need to handle such case in the future. By the way, I never used `array` type ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18374/discussion-between-djcloud23-and-j0k)